# Permutation: President and Vice-President

Tags: combinatorics, algebra-precalculus

Al, Bert, Carl, Don, Ernie and Fred are $6$ men in a club that is electing a President and Vice-President.  In how many ways can this be done if Carl and Fred cannot be together as President an Vice-President?

My answer is: $480$ ways

Comment: You should include in your posts your thought process, not just a numerical value.

Answer (score 3):

Twenty eight.

You can make $30$ choices of a President and Vice-President of $6$ men: any one of the $6$ can be elected as a President, then any of the remaining 5 as a Vice-President, and that makes $6\cdot 5=30$.
But two of possible results, Carl+Fred and Fred+Carl, are forbidden, hence the answer $30-2 = 28$.

Or more generally: there is $\frac{n!}{(n-k)!}$ *k*-permutations of *n*, so in your problem there is $\frac{6!}{(6-2)!}$ possible choices, $\frac{2!}{(2-2)!}$ of which are forbidden, giving a result of $6\cdot 5 - 2=28$.

You may also describe it with specific sequences of events: first elect a President, which makes $6$ possibilities; then if a President is Carl or Fred, choose one of four for a Vice-President, otherwise choose on of five.
Finally there are $2\cdot 4 + 4\cdot 5 = 28$ outcomes.

Answer (score 0):

According to me the answer is quite less.

Lets make cases for this situation. 
We have 2 positions to be filled-

____         ____

Pres.        V. Pres.

We have A,B,C,D,E,F

Case 1 - When none of C & F are selected.

4C2 × 2!

Case 2 - When one of C & F are selected.

2C1 × 4C1 × 2!

Case 3 - When both of them are selected.

2C2 × 2!

On solving we get-
 12 + 16 + 2 = 30 ways

Subtract the cases in which they are together

We get 28 ways

Comment: You could have stopped after Case 2.